# Retrieve src value from xmi files

Tags: xslt

I have set of xml files from which I have to retrieve the value present after src.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<org.eclipse.epf.uma:ContentDescription xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:org.eclipse.epf.uma="http://www.eclipse.org/epf/uma/1.0.6/uma.ecore" xmlns:rmc="http://www.ibm.com/rmc" rmc:version="7.5.1" xmlns:epf="http://www.eclipse.org/epf" epf:version="1.5.1" xmi:id="-ES_igec88m8mZhEXekVK3A" name="fs_evms,_zl9y8FCTEd6XXocT9rJgNQ" guid="-ES_igec88m8mZhEXekVK3A" changeDate="2009-08-01T13:54:29.422-0400" version="7.5.0">
  <mainDescription>&lt;p>&#xD;
    &lt;img alt=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;resources/IPMS_As-Is_75.jpg&quot; width=&quot;587&quot; height=&quot;346&quot; />&#xD;
&lt;/p></mainDescription>
</org.eclipse.epf.uma:ContentDescription>
```

or

```
 <sections xmi:id="_vlul8AKaEd6N9prBktGuYg" name="Update the opportunity information in Siebel" guid="_vlul8AKaEd6N9prBktGuYg">
    <sectionDescription>&lt;img alt=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;resources/UpdateOpportunity.JPG&quot; width=&quot;597&quot; height=&quot;360&quot; /></sectionDescription>
  </sections>
```

The hierarchy and values of the nodes very from one xml file to another. Please let me know how to retrieve the value of src from the above data using xslt.

Regards,
Kiran

Comment: The xmi file format is like below :

<Child1><img .../></Child1>

<Child2>...</Child2>

<Child3><img...</Child3>

</Parent>

the < before image is in the format &lt the quotes are in &quot; format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XSLT is severely limited with your input, because the escaped markup is not XML. You need to extract the desired portion using string functions - for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[contains(text(), 'src=&quot;')]">
            <url>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., 'src=&quot;'), '&quot;')"/>
            </url>
        </xsl:for-each>    
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access any xml file like this..

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

public class Sample
{
public static void Main()
{

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<book genre='novel' ISBN='1-861001-57-5'>" +
            "<title>Pride And Prejudice</title>" +
            "</book>");

XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

// Check to see if the element has a genre attribute. 
if (root.HasAttribute("genre")){
  String genre = root.GetAttribute("genre");
  Console.WriteLine(genre);
```

}

}
}

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017692/c-sharp-get-values-from-xml-attributes

Comment: The img attribute is not in the root node. It can be present in any node. The node name and the heirarchy of the nodes vary from file to file. Is there a way to get src attribute from all the xmi files irrespective of the node structure ?