# Parsing XML Using C# in uwp Xaml

Tags: c#, xml, uwp-xaml

How do you get the data from description in the tag something: `<something description = "something else"> </something>` using c# in uwp.

Comment: Hi, Do you want to get the XAML element's property value in C#?

Comment: I want to get the value from an attribute in xml using c#.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# get values from xml attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017692/c-sharp-get-values-from-xml-attributes)

Comment: @QA1 Hi, please state your question clearly. Do you want to know how to get the elements defined in XAML in the C# code, or do you want to know how to parse the XML document?

Comment: I want to get an attribute value from a tag in an xml document.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the test code to show how to get the XML node attribute value:

```cs
private void GetContent()
{
    string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><body><content title =\"XML File!\"></content></body>";
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    var tags=doc.GetElementsByTagName("content");
    if (tags.Count > 0)
    {
        var firstContent = tags.First();
        string result = firstContent.Attributes.GetNamedItem("title").InnerText;
    }
}
```

---

### Tips

1. In UWP, loading an `XmlDocument` via a path is not recommended. It is best to get the XML file first, read all the text, and load the `XmlDocument` via text.
2. The XmlDocument prefix namespace is `Windows.Data.Xml.Dom`, NOT `System.Xml`

Best regards.